# ERROR: ERROR: relationship "chat" does not exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created a trigger in postgresql, here is my code:

```
create trigger messages_added
after update 
on chat 
for each row 
execute procedure chat_expired();
```

But when I execute, I get the error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: relationship "chat" does not exist
```

yet according to the documentation, that's how you define a trigger and the cat table does exist in the database.

Comment: Maybe "cat" does exist, but it seems "chat" does not.  Not in the correct schema, anyway.

Comment: What is that tchat is a table that I previously created so I no longer defined it in the SQL tool that I used to create my trigger and I don't think it be mandatory to import a database in a sql tool so that it can be spotted by postgresql.